# How well does Ubuntu handle real time audio?

Tags: sound

I want to ditch Windows for one of my PC's because Windows can't handle my music without stuttering due to latencies. How well can Ubuntu handle real time audio? I need low latency.

Comment: Can't handle your music as in for production? Or just playing back MP3s?

Comment: you may want to consider Ubuntu Studio for serious music production.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the low latency kernel package with the Software Center, or using APT:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-lowlatency
```

If using the low latency kernel doesn't work for you, you have a different issue.

If you want to make it permanent, see [How do I pin the lowlatency kernels so apt doesn't update with a newer generic kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351602/how-do-i-pin-the-lowlatency-kernels-so-apt-doesnt-update-with-a-newer-generic-k)